# GWT Popup and UIBinder: Panel or DialogBox?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have a requirement where, when a button is clicked, the user should be prompted with a popup/dialog box to enter some additional details such as last name, DOB, etc.I tried to play with `window.confirm()` but I think this does not serve my purpose. Can some help me how this can be achieved in GWT through UIBinder?

I tried some thing like this in my UI binder.xml

```
<g:HTMLPanel visible="false" >
                                    <g:DialogBox ui:field="dialogPanel"
                                        animationEnabled="true" modal="false" glassEnabled="false">
                                        <g:caption>More Details</g:caption>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                    <g:Datepicker ui:field="DOB">DOB:</g:Datepicker>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>UserName:</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <g:TextBox ui:field="usernameTextBox" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <g:Button ui:field="loginButton">OK</g:Button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </g:DialogBox>
                                </g:HTMLPanel>
```

I am not sure which one to go with: popup or dialog box!

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the skeleton for a GWT Dialog box using uibinder:

MyDialogBox.java

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class MyDialogBox extends DialogBox {
    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyDialogBox> {
    }
    public MyDialogBox() {
        setWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
        setAutoHideEnabled(true);
        setText("My Title");
        setGlassEnabled(true);
         center();
    } 
}
```

MyDialog.ui.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <ui:style>
        .panel {
            background-color: ivory;
        }
    </ui:style>
    <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.panel}">
    <g:Label>Dialog Content</g:Label>
    </g:FlowPanel>
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

show it using:

```
MyDialogBox m = new MyDialogBox();
m.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`DialogBox`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) is a child of [`PopupPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) and has all its features. Additionally it has (from the docs):

```
..caption area at the top and can be dragged by the user.
```

About usage in UiBinder (again from the docs):

```
DialogBox elements in UiBinder templates can have one widget child and one 
<g:caption> child.
```

So it seems that you need to replace your `<table>` with a GWT widget, most probably `<g:HTMLPanel>` and put whole `<table>` inside it.

Also, PopupPanel and DialogBox are standalone widgets and normally do not get added to other Widgets, but are shown via `.show()` and `hide()` methods. So, in your UiBinder, you can put 
`<g:DialogBox>` at the root level.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.I was able get this working with just a minor change.I still had the Html wrapped around the dialogBox tags.I had to call the  dialogBox.center() inside my UiHandler method.